# shorter way for ajax large form submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Everything works here, but I need a shorter way, if possible, wherever you see **... 20 items**:

```
<input type='text' id='inputname' maxlength='50' placeholder='Name' required>
<input type='text' id='inputsname' maxlength='50' placeholder='Surname'>
... and so on... 20 fields.
<button id='btnregister'>Register</button>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#btnregister').click(function(){
var name = $('#inputname').val();
var sname = $('#inputsname').val();
... 20 items
$.ajax({
    url: 'regpro.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        'name': name,
        'sname': sname,
        ... 20 items
        },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'exists') {
            alert ('name allready exists');
        }
        else if (data =='empty'){
            alert ('something is missing');
        }
        else{
            location.href = 'login.php?ref="reg"';
        }
    }
});
});
```

**regpro.php**

```
$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
extract($_POST);
try {
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (name, sname... 20 items) VALUES (:name, :sname... 20 items)');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ":name" => $name,
    ":sname" => $sname,
    ... 20 items
));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I know classic form submitting instead of ajax procedure would be some shorter way on javascript side, but I want to keep inputs filled after processing, in case something is wrong, so user must not fill them all again.

On php side, maybe there is a way to say something like this:
`foreach post variable - find corresponding column - and insert variable value`

Comment: In your `data:` parameter in the `$ajax`-function, you can use: `data: $("#the-form-id").serialize(),` instead of enter them all yourself. That will give you an object with all the inputs/selects etc in the form.

Comment: Btw, since you're using prepared statements, the row `$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );` isn't needed and might just change the data unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by serialize data. try this.

```
$('#btnregister').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'regpro.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: $('#your-form-id').serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    ...
  }
 });
});
```